# Database Project with scalar functions as CHECK constraints

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-design, visual-studio-2013

I've seen some related posts on SO, but haven't been able to figure out what is happening here. I have a Database Project in Visual Studio 2013. Here is some code for a simple "Users" table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ID] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [Password] BINARY(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Users_Email] UNIQUE ([Email]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Users] CHECK ([dbo].[CheckUserIsValid]([Users].[Name], [Users].[Email]) = 1)
)
```

And here is the code for CheckUserIsValid:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckUserIsValid]
(
    @name NVARCHAR(50),
    @email NVARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS BIT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

    IF @name = ''
            OR @email = ''
            OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].[BlockedEmails]
                      WHERE [dbo].[BlockedEmails].[Email] = @email)
            OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                      FROM [dbo].[ApprovalCodes]
                      WHERE [dbo].[ApprovalCodes].[Email] = @email)
        RETURN 0

    RETURN 1

END
```

Now, the weird part is that when I open the code files BEFORE building the project, VS does not show any errors. When I try to build it, the build fails and I get a couple of different errors:

1. SQL04121: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.CheckUserIsValid", or the name is ambiguous. (this one is thrown on the Users table)
2. SQL00208: Invalid object name 'dbo.BlockedEmails'. (this one is thrown on the function)

I've read this may have something to do with how I am using a scalar function in my check constraint. Pretty stuck now though. Not sure what to try next.

**UPDATE**

So, if I leave the function unchanged, but change the table to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ID] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    [Password] BINARY(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [IX_Users_Email] UNIQUE ([Email])
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_Users] CHECK ([dbo].[CheckUserIsValid]([Users].[Name], [Users].[Email]) = 1)
GO
```

then bizarrely it builds fine. What the heck?

Comment: Before you spend too much effort on getting the database project to understand this model, you might want to investigate whether you really want to use check constraints and functions together. [Just spend a few minutes on the first few hits here](http://www.google.com/search?q=check+constraints+in+udfs+kuznetsov).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks. I just read through a bunch of those as you suggested. For my particular use case, I don't think I will run into any trouble. Even if I do decide to change the model as you recommend, I'd like to understand what I am doing wrong here.